# Laravel 6.x - Cache 'pagination()'

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel pagination (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)
like this:

```
// the Controller contains
$users = App\User::paginate(15);
```

Running this code, I noticed that are executed two queries:

1. To get the number of total items: `select count(*) as aggregate from user`
2. To get the first 15 items: `select * from user limit 15 offset 0`

I'd like to cache this queries, and the question is: from `App\User::paginate(15)` is there a way to get the **sql**(s) that will be executed? `select count(*) as aggregate from user` and `select * from user limit 15 offset 0`?

The code `App\User::paginate(15)` return a `LengthAwarePaginator` class; can I get the **sql** executed from this class?

The idea is to create my own method to cache this pagination request. Something like:

```
// the Model contains
public static function paginateWithQueryCache($itemPerPage) {
   $query = self::query();
   $cacheKeyString = $query->toSql();
   $cacheKeyStringMD5 = md5($cacheKeyString);
   return \Cache::remember($cacheKeyStringMD5, 60, function() use ($itemPerPage) {
            return self::paginate($itemPerPage);
        });
}
```

```
// the Controller will be update with
$users = App\User:: paginateWithQueryCache(15);
```

The problem here is that the `$query->toSql()` used as a cache key, is a simple query to the model (`select * from user`) instead of a pagination query (`select * from user limit 15 offset 0`); this is a problem switching to second page, **page=2**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The query `select count(*) as aggregate from user` (that is very slow in my case with millions of records in a database table) is executed from `Illuminate\Database\Query::getCountForPagination()`, then to cache it I need to extend the class and implement the cache.

I changed the approach and I decided to cache all pagination output:

```
    // Controller
    public function paginateCache($model, $cacheExpireInSeconds = 120) 
    {
        $cacheKeyString = request()->fullUrl();
        $cacheKeyStringMD5 = md5($cacheKeyString);

        /* Closure to get data */
        $func_get_data = function() use ($model) {
            return $model::paginate(1000);
        };

        /* Caching */
        return \Cache::remember($cacheKeyStringMD5, $cacheExpireInSeconds, $func_get_data);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->paginateCache(User::class);
    }
```